# Como obter informações das celulas do Excel utilizando VB

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-basic-6

Estou tentando pegar informações de uma coluna no Excel utilizando VB. Vamos supor que tenho 5 linhas e apenas 2 delas estão preenchidas com alguma informação e as outras 3 estão nulas.

Preciso de um código que pegue apenas essas duas linhas e quando ele chegar na terceira e ver que está nulo pare o programa e me passe apenas as duas informações que estão preenchidas.

Consegui com um código, mas determinei ele da linha `A1` até `A5` por exemplo para ele pegar as informações e caso tenha mais ele não fará a busca na `A6` por exemplo. Quero otimizar isso e ele sozinho saiba que tem mais e pegue apenas as linhas que estão preenchidas e esquece as nulas.

Código que tentei; Determinei a linha que ele pegara as informações e ele não fará a busca automática caso exista uma linha `B29`.

```
 Dim Cel, A1, A2
 A1 = "B23"
 A2 = "B28"
 Cel = GetCells(A1&":"&A2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um laço `for` que lê o valor da variável, armazena e pula uma linha para abaixo; Se a próxima linha for vazia ele para e sai do laço, senão ele continua.

No exemplo abaixo fiz de uma forma mais explicada, com variável auxiliar `x`, mas você pode fazer direto através de um código mais conciso.

```
Sub exemplo()

Dim x, NumRows, temp As Integer

Range("A1").Select 'Seta o ponto inicial da sua verificação
NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 'Pega o total de linhas com valor e salva em uma variável

For x = 1 To NumRows

 temp = ActiveCell.Value 'Aqui vc pega o valor da célula atual (começa em A1 e vai incrementando a cada laço)
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Pula para a linha de baixo
 Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: O VBA é uma linguagem estranha, então com `Dim x, NumRows, temp As Integer` somente temp está declarada como Integer, as outras estão como Variant. E fazer for loop com Select pode tornar o código lento, mas isso para mais de 1000 linhas.

Comment: Max, tudo bem? teria alguma forma de utilizar o GetCells ao em vez de Range?